# R generate random numeric for each row

Tags: r, paste, numeric

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> head(df.data)
Date Persnr AmountHolidays Season Holiday Temp
1 201101  55312            0.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
2 201101  55316            3.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
3 201101  55325            0.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
4 201101  76065            0.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
5 201101  71928            1.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
6 201101  72558            0.5    Off   FALSE  4.8

> str(df.data)
'data.frame':   490 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date          : Factor w/ 49 levels "201101","201102",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Persnr        : int  55312 55316 55325 76065 71928 72558 73045 77214 121216 71951 ...
 $ AmountHolidays: num  0 3 0 0 1 0.5 0 0.5 2 0 ...
 $ Season        : chr  "Off" "Off" "Off" "Off" ...
 $ Holiday       : chr  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" ...
 $ Temp          : num  4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 ...
```

What I wanted to do is to create a random value of two numbers and paste it behind the "Date" values. The two numbers represent the days.
For example "20110112" or "20110106".
I've used this already:

```
df.data$Date<-paste(df.data$Date,sample(1:31,31),sep="")
```

Result:

```
> head(df.data)
      Date Persnr AmountHolidays Season Holiday Temp
1 20110117  55312            0.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
2 20110114  55316            3.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
3  2011018  55325            0.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
4 20110113  76065            0.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
5  2011017  71928            1.0    Off   FALSE  4.8
6 20110110  72558            0.5    Off   FALSE  4.8
```

It works, BUT! my problem is that it does not always generate two numeric values. Value 1 is displayed as 1 and not 01. Value 2 is displayed as 2 and not 02 etc.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Try `sprintf('%s%02d', unique(df.data$Date), sample(1:31,31))`

Comment: In the example, `df.data$date` is the same, does it change?

Comment: Hi minhphongb.  Just for future reference please try to trim your question down to the part you can't figure out.  We don't want a case of the XY problem to arise but in this case you probably could have posted a question along the lines of "How do I format 1 as '01'?" - maybe a little more detail than that but you will get more replies and better replies if the question is short and to the point but still covers all the necessary bases.

Comment: @Dason will remember for next time ;)

Comment: Or `paste(df.data$Date,sprintf('%02d',sample(1:31,31)),sep="")`  A better example would have been easier to test

Comment: @akun you probably meant `paste0(df.data$Date, sprintf('%02d', sample(31)))`. Oh we posted at the same time :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Yes, but I would like to use it only with `sprintf` call.  The problem with the `sprintf` alone is the lengths need to be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
paste0(df.data$Date, sprintf('%02d', sample(31)))
```